# Getting warning message 'getDefaultMiddleware' is deprecated

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-devtools

I am getting a `getDefaultMiddleware` is deprecated warning after updating `"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1"` So how should I remove this warning. Do we have any other way to inject default middleware in the `configureStore` function?

```js
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import api from "./middleware/api";
export default function storeConfigure() {
   const store = configureStore({
   reducer,
   middleware: [
      ...getDefaultMiddleware(), 
      api
    ],
  });
  return store;
}
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The `middleware` option in `configureStore` accepts a callback function, and that callback will be given `getDefaultMiddleware` as its argument:

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(logger),
})
```

Use that instead of the separately imported version.

Comment: What if I want to `concat` multiple custom middleware? when I am adding multiple custom middlewares app stopped working.

Comment: You should be able to pass multiple middleware to a single `concat` call as far as I know. If for some reason that doesn't work, do several `concat` calls in a row.

Comment: Does `logger` need to be imported? If so, from where? Is it even necessary?

Comment: That's just an example of adding _a_ middleware, such as https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger .  Replace `logger` with whatever middleware you actually want to add.

Comment: For anyone arriving from google curious about why it's getting deprecated, these 2 RTK Github issue threads are a great read: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/958#issuecomment-875538589 & https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/1324

Comment: @markerikson can i confirm that for multiple middlewares, it should look like this, `getDefaultMiddleware().concat(thunk).concat(track).concat(logger)`?

Comment: @CompaqLE2202x : You should be able to pass multiple middleware to a single `concat()` call, like `.concat(track, logger)` - `getDefaultMiddleware()` returns an array, albeit one with improved TS types and a `.prepend()` method.  Note that `thunk` is already part of `getDefaultMiddleware()` and you don't need to add that manually.

Comment: Based on this answer, how to disable the logger on production? Do I have to write a condition like:
```
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      return getDefaultMiddleware().concat(logger)
    }
    return getDefaultMiddleware();
  },
```

Comment: Yeah, any sort of conditional check like that would work.

Answer (score 13):

Can use like that:

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => [...getDefaultMiddleware(), api],
})
```

A callback return an array of middle ware, it's will be cleaner and easy to read.

Comment: The redux toolkit docs says that it is good practice to use the concat array method instead of array destructuring in this particular scenario... just letting you know ✌️

Comment: For clarity, the paragraph @georgewashingmachine is referring to reads: "It is preferable to use the chainable .concat(...) and .prepend(...) methods of the returned MiddlewareArray instead of the array spread operator, as the latter can lose valuable type information under some circumstances." at https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware

Answer (score 0):

getDefaultMiddleware is deprecated, you might need to add them as an array like this.

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [thunk, logger],
})
```

Note: You will be responsible to add all the middlewares you'll need as getDefaultMiddleware() comes with several other middlewares(Most of them are for development purpose except createAsyncThunk).

If you need to add them, you can do like this;

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [
    createActionCreatorInvariantMiddleware,
    createImmutableStateInvariantMiddleware,
    createAsyncThunk,
    createSerializableStateInvariantMiddleware,
  ]});
```

Remember to import them above in your code.