# how to configure redux sagas with redux toolkit and typescript?

Tags: typescript, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

This is my store :

```html
import saga from 'redux-saga';
import {all, fork} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import { watchCommonSaga} from './sagas';
import RootReducer from './slices';

function* RootSaga(){
    yield all([fork(watchCommonSaga)]);
}

const sagaMiddleware = saga();

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: RootReducer,
    middleware: [
        ...getDefaultMiddleware({thunk: false, serializableCheck: false}),
        sagaMiddleware
    ],
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
})

sagaMiddleware.run(RootSaga);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>

export default store;
```

, **The problem is that getDefaultMiddleware is deprecated.:**,
How i can solve this? I can't find updated documentation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68479631/getting-warning-message-getdefaultmiddleware-is-deprecated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting warning message 'getDefaultMiddleware' is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68479631/getting-warning-message-getdefaultmiddleware-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 2):

Use concat() to add another reducer to middleware.

I edit your code:

```
import saga from 'redux-saga';
import {all, fork} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import { watchCommonSaga} from './sagas';
import RootReducer from './slices';

function* RootSaga(){
    yield all([fork(watchCommonSaga)]);
}
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        reducer: RootReducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck: false,
        thunk: false
      }).concat(sagaMiddleware)
})

sagaMiddleware.run(RootSaga);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>


export default store;
```

Comment: I've not seen any documentation on putting "thunk: false" anywhere, but that one line fixed everything for me. THANK YOU

Comment: @discodane Yea, there is not documentation and I use this with ReduxToolkit addListener feature, which using thunk and it work with thunk: false. So it's very hard to say what happening on background of this parameters.