# Error - [Redux-Toolkit] - each middleware provided to configureStore must be a function

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I was trying to setup redux in my existing React project using redux toolkit by following the official documentation.

I tried configuring the middleware

```
import { configureStore, MiddlewareArray } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: new MiddlewareArray().concat(logger),
})

configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [logger] as const,
})
```

However, I get the below error.

[image]

I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/68486869, it didn't help

Can anyone help here

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. Both those examples look like they should *run*, in theory.  But neither of them is what we show or recommend in the docs.

The "right" answer should be:

```js
configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(logger)
})
```

You should never have to call `new MiddlewareArray()` yourself.  That's a type that gets returned from `getDefaultMiddleware()` already.  You also don't normally want to do `[someMiddleware]`, because that means that none of the default middleware will get included.

Comment: I am using typescript. I had to declare redux-logger module in .d.ts file. It worked. Thanks. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @markerikson I have been tried this and it's working fine thanks.