# How to get middlewares from getDefaultMiddleware

Tags: node.js, react-redux

```
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from "../features/user/userSlice";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  },
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: false,
  }),
});
```

I am getting a getDefaultMiddleware is deprecated. How should I remove this warning

Comment: This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68486869/17139797).

Comment: @Gaurav Just FYI, if posts have already been answered then a more appropriate action could be to vote to close as a duplicate, or flag as a duplicate if you don't have the rep access just yet.